# How do I create an enum from a string in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have an enum with some instances `Foo` and `Bar`.  If I have a string `"Foo"`, how can I instantiate a `Foo` enum from that?  In C# it would be `Enum.Parse(...)`, is there an equivalent in Kotlin?

Currently, the best I have found is to create a factory that switches on all possible strings, but that is error prone and performs poorly for large enumerations.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Kotlin enum classes have "static" function `valueOf`  to get enum entry by string(like Java enums). Additionally they have "static" function `values` to get all enum entries. Example:

```
enum class MyEnum {
  Foo, Bar, Baz
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  println(MyEnum.valueOf("Foo") == MyEnum.Foo)
  println(MyEnum.valueOf("Bar") == MyEnum.Bar)
  println(MyEnum.values().toList())
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to override this at all? For example, if I wanted to implemented my own version that was case insensitive.

Comment: It's impossible, AFAIK it's impossible Java too. Introducing own method isn't suitable for your case?

Comment: Doing my own method is fine sure, but it would just be nice to use an existing method so that users don't need to worry about what this `valueOfIgnoringCase` method is, they just use `valueOf` like normal

Comment: @Developine this links to a 5 billionth search winner for me. You should check if you site has malware.

Comment: Can I also do the reverse of that as well? (i.e. get the name of Kotlin enum class from one of its enum-entry).

Comment: @gxyd sure, there is the property `name` for that.

Answer (score 38):

As `bashor` suggested, use `MyEnum.valueOf()` but please have in mind that it throws an exception if value can't be found. I recommend using:

```
enum class MyEnum {
  Foo, Bar, Baz
}

try {
   myVar = MyEnum.valueOf("Qux")
} catch(e: IllegalArgumentException) {
   Log.d(TAG, "INVALID MyEnum value: 'Qux' | $e")
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Would do it like

```
enum class MyEnum {
  Foo, Bar, Baz
}

val value = MyEnum.values().firstOrNull {it.name == "Foo"} // results to MyEnum.Foo
```

Answer (score 16):

### Reusable Exception Safe Solution

The default solution in Kotlin will throw an exception. If you want a reliable solution that works statically for all enums, try this!

Now just call `valueOf<MyEnum>("value")`. If the type is invalid, you'll get null and have to handle it, instead of an exception.

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String): T? {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a default value, calling `valueOf<MyEnum>("value", MyEnum.FALLBACK)`, and avoid a null response. You can extend your specific enum to have the default be automatic

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T {
    return try {
        java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        default
    }
}
```

Or if you want both, make the second:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> valueOf(type: String, default: T): T = valueOf<T>(type) ?: default
```

Comment: Using java.lang.Enum.valueOf is a great tip! I needed to create an enum from a string, but I only have a Class<E> and therefore I cannot use Kotlin valueOf.

Comment: Returning a null is unsafe Either a sensitive value is returned or the exception is thrown. Null pointer creator has claimed many times about avoiding it.
REF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare

In fact, Kotlin puts lot of efforts trying to avoid it while keeping compatibility with Java. Throwing an error is just a way to avoid it. Returning a null is still an error, but it will not fail-fast. <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast_system>

Modern languages with no need for backward compatibility just fix the problem by not having nulls at all (https://vlang.io/)

Answer (score 15):

If you want to create an enum constant from one of its properties, instead of the name, this funny code does a pretty decent job:

```
import kotlin.enums.enumEntries
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty1

@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>, V> KProperty1<T, V>.findOrNull(value: V): T? =
    enumEntries<T>().firstOrNull { this(it) == value }

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>, V> KProperty1<T, V>.find(value: V): T =
    findOrNull(value) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException(
        "Could not find enum constant with property `$name` of value `$value`"
    )
```

These can be used like this:

```
enum class Algorithms(val string: String) {
    Sha1("SHA-1"),
    Sha256("SHA-256"),
}

fun main() {
    // This will print `Sha256`
    println(Algorithms::string.findOrNull("SHA-256"))

    // This will crash with:
    // IllegalArgumentException: Could not find enum constant with property `string` of value `SHA-420`
    Algorithms::string.find("SHA-420")
}
```

If not using Kotlin 1.9.20 or beyond, replace `enumEntries` with [the less efficient](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants:%7E:text=In%20Kotlin%201.9.20,far%20more%20efficient.) `enumValues`. This also does not require opting into experimental APIs.

Note also that string interpolation consumes resources and may lead to bugs, so depending on your use case you may want to create a custom parametrized exception, or just not include the details when constructing the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 7):

You can create this kind of enum class which will take a string and convert it to enum type

```
enum class EmployeeType(val value: String) {
    Contractor("CONTRACTOR"),
    FullTime("FULL_TIME"),
    PartTime("PART_TIME");

    companion object {
        public fun fromValue(value: String): EmployeeType = when (value) {
            "CONTRACTOR" -> Contractor
            "FULL_TIME"  -> FullTime
            "PART_TIME"  -> PartTime
            else         -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the best solution is `enumValueOf<T>(String)`:

```
enum class MyEnum { Foo, Bar }

@Test
fun test() {
  assertEquals(MyEnum.Foo, enumValueOf<MyEnum>("Foo"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use parameter like : `val rgb: Int`
for example :

```kotlin
enum class Color(val rgb: Int) {
    RED(0xFF0000),
    GREEN(0x00FF00),
    BLUE(0x0000FF)
}
```

so that for `Int` and you can use `String` for all items like bellow :

```kotlin
enum class NoteStatus(val value: String) {
    PENDING("PENDING"),
    PLANNING("PLANNING"),
    USED("USED")
}
```

and you can use like this :

```kotlin
data class MoneyNoteData (
    val name: String,
    val value: Int,
    val status: NoteStatus = NoteStatus.USED
)
```