# Sort a list of Class by a specific attribute

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

Hi I'm new in android development (kotlin), here is my problem:
I have an ArrayList class (ProductStore), in this class there is another class (StorageType) in which there is a string (libellus) with which I want to sort my ArrayList (or rather constitute groups where the string (libellus) is identical. How can I do it?

```
data class Stock(
    val product: ArrayList<ProductStore>
)

class ProductStore {
    var quantity: Double? = null
    val expiration_date: String? = null
    val product: Product? = null
    val storage_type: StorageType? = null
    val quantity_type: QuantityType? = null
}

class Product{
    val id: Double? =  null
    val name: String? = null
    val image: String? =null
}

class StorageType{
    val id: Double? = null
    val libellus: String? = null
}

class QuantityType{
    val libellus: String? = null
}
```

Comment: I think this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169017/13373575

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of object in kotlin with custom order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402219/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-in-kotlin-with-custom-order)

Answer (score 1):

The question title is a good hint on what you need to do ;-) Just use [sortedBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html)
function:

```kotlin
val list: List<ProductStore> = ...

val sorted = list.sortedBy { it.storage_type?.libellus }
```

You said you use `ArrayList`, so if you prefer to sort in-place then you can use `sortBy()` instead.

Depending on where do you need to place `null` items (on top or on the bottom), you may need to modify this code.

> or rather constitute groups where the string (libellus) is identical

If this is the case then you may not need to do sorting at all. You can group items like this:

```kotlin
val grouped = list.groupBy { it.storage_type?.libellus }
```

It gives you a map where keys are `libellus` strings and values are lists of their associated `ProductStore` objects.

Comment: Thank you for this answer it helps me a lot however as I know the value "libelus" is going to be (fresh, ambient or frozen) I would like to create groups from these values

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. It sounds like `groupBy()` should do exactly what you need - it will give you: `fresh`, `ambient`, etc. groups.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your code inside `main` method. But first I had to convert `ProductStore()`, `Product()`, `StorageType()` and `QuantityType()` normal Kotlin Classes to [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) in order to easily print them as a String using the implicit `toString()`.

I then made an example of the `Stock Data Class` as follows:

```
fun main() {
    
    //instance of the Stock Class
    val stock = Stock(
        product = arrayListOf(
            ProductStore(
                storage_type = StorageType(libellus = "frozen"),
                quantity = 13.0,
                expiration_date = "",
                product = Product(),
                quantity_type = QuantityType()
            ), ProductStore(
                storage_type = StorageType(libellus = "fresh"),
                quantity = 18.0,
                expiration_date = "",
                product = Product(),
                quantity_type = QuantityType()
            ), ......}}
```

From here I just used [@broot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448875/broot) approach to group the `ArrayList of ProductStore` elements into a `Map` Object:

```
//grouping  the stock
    val productsGroups = stock.product.groupBy { productStore ->
        when (productStore.storage_type?.libellus) {

            "frozen" -> {
                "frozen"
            }
            "fresh" -> {
                "fresh"
            }
            else -> {
                "ambient"
            }

        }
    }
    println(productsGroups)
}
```

The output of `println(productsGroups)` was a printed `Map Object` whereby the Stock's StorageType (***frozen, ambient, fresh***) was keys and corresponding lists as the values.

```
{frozen=[ProductStore(quantity=13.0, expiration_date=, product=Product(id=null, name=null, image=null), storage_type=StorageType(id=null, libellus=frozen), quantity_type=QuantityType(libellus=null))], 

fresh=[ProductStore(quantity=18.0, expiration_date=, product=Product(id=null, name=null, image=null), storage_type=StorageType(id=null, libellus=fresh), quantity_type=QuantityType(libellus=null))], 

ambient=[ProductStore(quantity=2021.0, expiration_date=, product=Product(id=null, name=null, image=null), storage_type=StorageType(id=null, libellus=ambient), quantity_type=QuantityType(libellus=null))]}
```